# I need some help.. oxyplot LogLogAxis

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

I creating LogLogarithmicAxis-log(log()) referring to OxyPlot's LogarithmicAxis -log()

this is my code
[OxyPlot.Axes.LogLogarithmicAxis.cs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lBKE6hXc5hMnKXv3PSRwRIXaY9HM5q9x)
[OxyPlot.Wpf.LogLogarithmicAxis.cs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pYNS5aMIal35ZavFM_DjNMSuAgPTrtRb)
[Examples/ExampleLibrary/Axes/LogarithmicAxisExamples.cs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sGN8NuIL0erqCw-NYplvWmHTlGp55ZAh)

chart image by code :
[chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbg7r.jpg)

but i need this style : 
[chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiBVI.jpg)

Comparing the two chart images, Tick and Label on Y axis are different.
how to coding...help..

Answer (score 1):

Please add a minimal, complete and viable example. And embed your code and images in the question. Someday you will remove the files from your google drive and the question won't be of help to anyone.

Comment: sorry... I tried to create a question with the source, but I kept getting an error. because ... I can not speak English, I am using Google Translator.